# How to work with files in XPCOM

Tags: c++, file, components, mozilla, xpcom

I'm writing a Mozilla component to get all the links from a page an write them into a file using XPCOM and C++.
I get all the links into an array like this:

```
//doc is a pointer to nsIDOMDocument
doc->GetElementsByTagName(NS_LITERAL_STRING("A"), getter_AddRefs(nodeList));
nodeList->GetLength(&nodeNumb);
href = new nsEmbedString[nodeNumb];

for(PRUnit32 i=0; i< nodeNumb; i++){
   nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMNode> aNode;
   nodeList->Item(i, getter_AddRefs(aNode));
   nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMHTMLAnchorElement> anchor = do_QueryInterface(aNode);
   if(anchor){
      (*outLinks)++;
      href[i] = anchor->GetHref(tempHref);  
   }
 } // end of for
```

but now how can I get them write to a file. I'm really clue less how to work with file in XPCOM. Can some one please give me some hints or links to tutorials please?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XPCOM, but is there a reason you can't use standard C++ streams?

Comment: @casablanca: XPCOM offers some support to find a reasonable location for such files in a platform-independent way. In practice, you'll find it insufficient on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably seen `nsIFile`, which does offer an `IsWriteable()` method but no `write()`. You'd want `nsILocalFile::openANSIFileDesc()`, which returns an ordinary `FILE*`.

Comment: That means you have to worry about closing the file yourself and leaves you to deal with platform specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an [nsIFileOutputStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/File_I%2F%2FO#Writing_to_a_file).